# Not able to serve jupyter notebooks in binder

Tags: python-3.x, docker, jupyter-notebook, raku

[Binder](https://mybinder.org/) project looks promising.
It helps in executing notebooks in a github repository by building an executable container.
I am trying to build an executable container in binder with the following `Dockerfile` that has **Perl 6** and **Python 3** kernels:

```
FROM sumdoc/perl-6

ENV NB_USER jovyan
ENV NB_UID 1000
ENV HOME /home/${NB_USER}

RUN adduser --disabled-password \
    --gecos "Default user" \
    --uid ${NB_UID} \
    ${NB_USER}


RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential \
    git wget libzmq3-dev ca-certificates python3-pip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && pip3 install jupyter notebook --no-cache-dir \
    && zef -v install https://github.com/bduggan/p6-jupyter-kernel.git --force-test \
    && jupyter-kernel.p6 --generate-config





ENV TINI_VERSION v0.16.1
ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini /usr/bin/tini
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/tini 
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/tini", "--"]
COPY . ${HOME}
USER root
RUN chown -R ${NB_UID} ${HOME}
USER ${NB_USER}

EXPOSE 8888

CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--allow-root"]
```

Binder launches this window after building a container:
[image]

While trying to run `Perl 6` or `Python 3` notebook I get this error:
[image]

I read this [documentation on binder](http://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dockerfile.html#when-you-are-building-complex-software) but could not succeed.

What things I am missing? Any help with explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe add a `python3` (or whatever it's supposed to be) tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/master/base-notebook/Dockerfile), I solved the issue.

I even wrote a blog on using Perl 6 notebook in [Binder here](https://sumdoc.wordpress.com/2018/01/04/using-perl-6-notebooks-in-binder/).

What I was missing was to add `WORKDIR $HOME` after `USER ${NB_USER}`in my Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM sumankhanal/perl-6

ENV NB_USER jovyan
ENV NB_UID 1000
ENV HOME /home/${NB_USER}

RUN adduser --disabled-password \
    --gecos "Default user" \
    --uid ${NB_UID} \
    ${NB_USER}


RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential \
    git wget libzmq3-dev ca-certificates python3-pip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && pip3 install jupyter notebook --no-cache-dir \
    && zef -v install https://github.com/bduggan/p6-jupyter-kernel.git --force-test \
    && jupyter-kernel.p6 --generate-config





ENV TINI_VERSION v0.16.1
ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini /usr/bin/tini
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/tini 
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/tini", "--"]
COPY . ${HOME}
USER root
RUN chown -R ${NB_UID} ${HOME}
USER ${NB_USER}

WORKDIR ${HOME}

EXPOSE 8888

CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--allow-root"]
```